# printing 2D arraylist in spiral order indexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to print 2D arraylist in spiral order in Java. At any time, I mark boundaries between traversed and untraversed part of arraylist by means of variables t,b,l,r (the meaning of whose are given in code below). Also variable dir is for direction that I want to traverse.

```
dir=0(right),1(down),2(left),3(up).
```

Here's my code:

```
public class Solution {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE LIST
    public ArrayList<Integer> spiralOrder(final List<ArrayList<Integer>> a) {
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // Populate result;
        /*
         * m=no. of rows, n=no. of cols, t=top row of untraversed list, b=bottom
         * row of untraversed list, l=left most col of untraversed list and
         * r=right most col of untraversed list
         */
        int m = a.size();
        int n = a.get(0).size();
        int dir = 0;
        int t = 0;
        int b = m - 1;
        int l = 0;
        int r = n - 1;
        while (l <= r && t <= b) {
            if (dir == 0) {
                for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
                    result.add(a.get(t).get(i));
                    dir = 1;
                    t++;
                }
            } else if (dir == 1) {
                for (int i = t; i <= b; i++) {
                    result.add(a.get(i).get(r));
                    dir = 2;
                    r--;
                }
            } else if (dir == 2) {
                for (int i = r; i >= l; i--) {
                    result.add(a.get(b).get(i));
                    dir = 3;
                    b--;
                }
            } else if (dir == 3) {
                for (int i = b; i >= b; i++) {
                    result.add(a.get(i).get(l));
                    dir = 0;
                    l++;
                }
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point to me where am I making mistake? (I am getting IndexOutOfBounds Exception)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your request but I assumed for this matrix:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23
24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41
```

the output is this:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 35, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 30, 24, 18, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 22, 28, 34, 33, 32, 31, 25, 19, 13, 14, 15, 21, 27, 26, 20
```

Your algorithm is a little bit overcomplicated. The direction order is always the same: right, down, left, up. So you can write each `for` one after another without maintaining dir.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> spiralOrder(final List<ArrayList<Integer>> a) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int n = a.size();
    int m = a.get(0).size();
    for (int level = 0; level < Math.min(n, m) / 2; level++) {
        for (int i = level; i < m - level - 1; i++) {
            result.add(a.get(level).get(i));
        }
        for (int i = level; i < n - level - 1; i++) {
            result.add(a.get(i).get(m - level - 1));
        }
        for (int i = m - level - 1; i > level; i--) {
            result.add(a.get(n - level - 1).get(i));
        }
        for (int i = n - level - 1; i > level; i--) {
            result.add(a.get(i).get(level));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small error updating your variable t,l,r,b.
After processing left to right, do t++ once. Currently was being updated with i everytime.
Updated code below. Hope this helps.

```
           while(l<=r && t<=b){
                 if(dir==0){
                     for(int i=l; i<=r;i++){
                         result.add(a.get(t).get(i));
                     }
                     dir=1;t++;
                     }

                     else if(dir==1){
                         for(int i=t;i<=b;i++){
                             result.add(a.get(i).get(r));
                         }
                         dir=2;r--;
                     }
                     else if(dir==2){
                         for(int i=r;i>=l;i--){
                             result.add(a.get(b).get(i));
                         }
                         dir=3;b--;
                     }
                     else if(dir==3){
                         for(int i=b;i>=t;i--){ // from bottom to top
                             result.add(a.get(i).get(l));
                         }
                         dir=0;l++;
                     }

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(dir==3){
    for(int i=b;i>=b;i++){
```

I think it should read i >= t (from bottom to top). If that's not it look at the stack trace and what array is out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
else if(dir==3){
    for(int i=b;i>=b;i++){
```

to:

```
else if (dir==3) {
     for(int i=b; i>=t; i--){
```

Answer (score -1):

```
else if (dir == 3) {
    for (int i = b; i >= t; i--) {
        result.add(a.get(i).get(l));
        dir = 0;
        l++;
    }
}
```